# pip3 command fails after upgrading to pip version 18.1

Tags: python, python3, pip

After upgrading pip3 using `$ pip3 install --upgrade pip`, pip3 fails to work.  And throws this:
Error Command:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/bin/pip3", line 9, in <module>
        from pip import main
    ImportError: cannot import name 'main'
```

it's having the same issue again even after removing the pip3 and reinstalling it.

Somewhere someone suggested to change the `from pip import main` to `from pip._internal import main`. But still it didn't work.

Comment: How did you install `pip3` in the first place? How did you reinstall it? What version of Ubuntu are you using? What is the output of `type -a pip pip3`?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

I've both Python 3.6 (as it comes pre-installed with the OS) and Python 3.7 (that I installed separately using [this](https://dzone.com/articles/install-python-370-on-ubuntu-1804debian-95)).

I used `sudo apt-get install python3-pip` to install pip3.

I did `sudo apt purge python3-pip` and `sudo rm -rf '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip'` to remove it and again used `sudo apt-get install python3-pip` to reinstall it. But still getting the same error.

And the output for this `type -a pip pip3` is, `pip is /usr/bin/pip
` and `pip3 is /usr/bin/pip3
`

Comment: Are you sure you ran `pip3 install --upgrade pip` to upgrade pip? Cause for upgrading the system version, you would need to use `sudo pip3 install --upgrade pip`, or for installing/upgrading your user version, you would need `pip3 install --upgrade --user pip`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49836676/error-after-upgrading-pip-cannot-import-name-main

Answer (score 0):

Your system-wide pip3 executable is still old and located at /usr/bin/pip3:

```
$ ll `which pip3`
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 293 May 16  2018 /usr/bin/pip3*
```

Try updating using sudo:

```
$ sudo pip3 install --upgrade pip
```

Then your updated pip3 executable should be placed at /usr/local/bin/pip3:

```
$ ll `which pip3`
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 216 Jan  8 20:46 /usr/local/bin/pip3*
```

and will be used by default.